# Is it okay that vacously true statements can be used to prove apparent contradictions?

Tags: logic

I am reading *How to prove it* by Velleman, and something is bothering me. On page 70, he states that "all unicorns are green" is vacuously true and so is "all unicorns are purple." He goes on to state that this two statements do not contradict each other and does not give any reasons why. This does not make sense to me. If both statements are considered to be true, the conclusion is that they contradict each other.

I understand the mathematical reasoning behind the conclusion, but that still does not explain why we should accept that both of the statements that are supposedly true do not contradict each other. Does this signal to a problem in the theory of quantificational logic mainly in how the conditional connector is defined?

Comment: The sentences are shorthands for "if there are unicorns then they are all green" and "if there are unicorns then they are all purple". Since there are no unicorns both sentences are true, they are implications with false premises, which are always true. And they obviously do not contradict each other.

Comment: @Conifold I understand. But if the implications translate to the sentences that I wrote above, which obviously contradict each other and can be considered true at the same time, would you agree that there might be something wrong in the translation at least?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the translation, other than what is always "wrong" with shorthands, they omit something. But even the shorthands do not "obviously" contradict each other unless one overlooks that unicorns may not exist. Perhaps, one could say that the conditional translation is "unnatural" and talking about something "presupposes" its existence, but if that were so we'd never be able to talk about fictions. So the "contradiction" really is just oversight, as in trick puzzles that target "implied meaning" habits.

Comment: In formal logic by definition vacuous truth only refers to the case of material implication p → q, so as long as you can arrive at Γ ⊢ p from your theory Γ, then you prove contradiction of your system. Say ∃x.Unicorn(x) is a non-logical axiom of your theory, then your book's conclusion doesn't follow. In free logic you can even make it more align with what you had in mind by adding an existence predicate E(x) after Unicorn(x) so that your book's seemingly controversial strange conclusion doesn't follow per our everyday reasoning...

Comment: The issue is a little bit tricky... For the Universal Affirmative: "every man is white", the corresponding negation (i.e. contradictory) is "there is a man that is not white". Applied to unicorns, the contradictory of the universal is "there is..." which is obviously FALSE (no unicorns at all). IF we agree on the modern translation of the above statements, this is the argument supporting "vacuous truth". But original analysis of Universal Affirmative by Aristotle does **not** consider the case with "empty terms" (like unicorns); thus, it was more similar to natural language understanding.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA There are logicians, such as Stephen Read, who would disagree with your claim that Aristotle does not consider empty terms. Aristotle does give examples about centaurs, for example. The whole issue of existential import is highly disputed, and there are at least three distinct interpretations of Aristotle.

Comment: @Bumble - Sure; in philosophy everyone disagree on everything. This is the reason why it is philosophy and not science.

Comment: While there's no immediate contradiction in asserting mutually-exclusive properties on all members of an empty-set, it'd seem entirely reasonable to observe that such a finding would highlight the underlying logic being flimsy.

Comment: @Nat There is no non-immediate contradiction either, and  such a finding would seem to be a perfectly solid application of the underlying logic.

Comment: @Conifold: It's like a [code-smell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell), where it'd seem indicative of a deeper issue.

Answer (score 5):

This seeming paradox comes from the difference between ordinary language and statements in a logical system. You are interpreting "all unicorns are green" as meaning something like "if there was a unicorn, it would be green." But Velleman intends it to express "for any object x, if x is a unicorn, x is green." This is vacuously true because there are no objects x, such that x is a unicorn.

In a logical framework such as the one Velleman is apparently using, there is something called a "universe of discourse" --a set of all objects which can be discussed in the language of that framework. Since unicorns are not in the universe of discourse, statements about them mean nothing, express nothing, and therefore cannot contradict each other.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct to be bothered by Vellemans statements.

First, Velleman is considering both of these statements in the context of formal logic. And when these statements are translated literally into that language, he is correct.

However, formal logic is not all of logic. Unicorns are mythical creatures and are not normally green or purple. If this understanding was formalised then you would be right, and Velleman, wrong.

Unfortunately, many people take formal logic to be a substitute for logic itself. This is quite wrong. Formal logic is only a small part of logic.

Answer (score 0):

All unicorns are green - this is vacuously true, because there are no unicorns.
All unicorns are purple - true for the same reason.

All unicorns are simultaneously green and purple and have six legs - also true.

Now if you didn't know that there are no unicorns, you could conclude logically from the first two statements that all unicorns are simultaneously green and purple. And if you assume that nothing can be simultaneously green and purple, you could draw the conclusion that there are no unicorns.

The first two statements would only contradict each other if you added another statement "there is at least one unicorn". But nobody makes that statement, so there is no contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

There is no contradiction in the logic, as formal logic defines how to handle vacuous statements.  The issue is that, when you attempt to phrase it in English, the resulting translation does not inspire you to use the same definitions.

I think the issue is that in the formal logic, we speak of entities.  The classes that we enumerate, such as "all unicorns," are nothing more than collections of entities.  In plain English, we often assign properties to the class, not just the individuals.  "All unicorns are green" could also be written as "unicorns are green" and still assign properties to the class of unicorns.

In logic we must keep focus on the fact that "all unicorns" is just enumerating entities in a class, nothing more.

And it's always nice to remember just how much we gain from accepting vacuous truths.  Many statements we make would become substantially more complicated to state if we didn't have this rule because you would constant have to pay attention to empty sets which have no properties.  And with all language, we can define any semantics we please, as long as both parties agree.  The fact that the phraseology that logicians agreed upon does not precisely match up with a common interpretation of English is unfortunate, but worth the price of communicating logically.

Answer (score -2):

Surely all statements that are true would become untrue if there were an example of something that contradicted them; for example the statement that all ants are black remains true until a red ant turns up.  In your example, there are two sets that would be contradictory if either set were not empty, however both are empty.  In a debate, though, a claim made without evidence may be struck down without evidence and so the idea of what counts as true varies somewhat according to the context.

Answer (score -3):

> "all unicorns are green" is vacuously true and so is "all unicorns are purple."

This isn't consistent with the standard logical intuitions of normal human beings. It is typical, however, of mathematical logic and Daniel J. Velleman is a mathematician.

It is unfortunate that many if not most mathematicians don't even seem to be aware that mathematical logic isn't logic. Logic is primarily a mental faculty, that is, it is a natural mental capacity, and since human beings are believed to have existed for about 500,000 years, logic already existed long before mathematical logic. The point is that whatever mathematical logic says, it is not going to change human logic.

Thus, the mathematical logic assertion that it is true that "all unicorns are green" can only be seriously perplexing to the normally intelligent reader. For this reason, it is literally an illogical assertion. It may be "true" in mathematical logic, but mathematical logic itself isn't true of anything. This is because the notion of vacuous truth only exists in mathematical logic. This notion has no counterpart in human deductive logic. It is a direct consequence of the use of the material implication as proxy for the logical implication and as such falsifies the idea that it is a good model of it.

A material implication φ ⊃ ψ is true if the first term φ is false. This directly, and logically, follows from the fact that φ ⊃ ψ is in fact ¬φ ∨ ψ and nothing else. The name "material implication" is itself misleading. A material implication is not even an implication. The term is a complete invention of mathematicians.

The notion of vacuous truth is suggested by the fact that the pseudo-modus ponens φ ∧ (φ ⊃ ψ) ⊢ ψ cannot be used to prove ψ when φ is false, even though it makes φ ⊃ ψ true. So, it is regarded as irrelevant to logical proofs.

One vexing consequence, however, is that both φ ⊃ ψ and φ ⊃ ¬ψ are true if φ is false. This is inconsistent with the standard concept of logical implication.

The fact that the two statements "all unicorns are green" and "all unicorns are purple" are deemed "true" in mathematical logic is a consequence of the material implication.

Mathematicians have come to use the expressions "vacuous truth" to defuse and undermine the frequent criticism of the material implication and of mathematical logic in general. It is a way to devaluate the significance of the case of false antecedents and of the case from inexistent subjects.